# some direction on webpack

Tags: webpack

I've been using bower as a way to control my front-end, but I've been hearing a bit about webpack, but honestly I can't find too many tutorials that's catering to how I'm using bower (which maybe I'm looking at  it wrong)

What I'm looking for is a way to build per page (page1.js, page2.js, etc) but I want my css, font files, etc to not be inlined (most tutorials show them as being inline and that makes me shutter)

is there a clean way to do all that in webpack? or should I just stick with bower (or just switch to npm and learn to use browserify)?

Comment: I have but it doesn't help as its assuming I have a one page app where I have a full web app with many pages/partials

Comment: thought so, just making sure.

Comment: why -1? if you're going to do that please explain yourself so I can try to resolve it

Comment: to multi page apps, you can check [multiple entry points](https://webpack.github.io/docs/multiple-entry-points.html). One of this entry can be a vendor bundle, that encapsulates all common code. And to extract css from inline you can use the popular [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin). Webpack docs are not so clear, unfortunately.

Comment: the doc is a bit hard, its harder finding something thats not react-related on the topic, I'm still trying to wrap my mind around it before I take the plunge and scrap bower from my workflow

Comment: I posted as answer. Didn't know any general tutorial.

Comment: @mrlew I have something [here](http://survivejs.com/webpack/introduction/). Not sure if general enough, though.

Comment: @Eman it was a -1 because of it being off topic (prior to the edit). I was planning to remove the downvote if you edit it and since you edited it they *should* let me un-downvote it but for some reason it won't let me. I can try making an arbitrary edit then un-downvoting.

Comment: @bebraw I saw this and it is a good tutorial, wish he'd use jQuery & bootstrap in his examples instead of react.

Comment: @Eman, jQuery and Bootstrap could use more content, yeah. Tons of material to cover. If you have specific ideas, poke me at [the issue tracker](https://github.com/survivejs/webpack/issues). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To multi page apps, you can check [multiple entry points](https://webpack.github.io/docs/multiple-entry-points.html). One of this entry can be a vendor bundle, that encapsulates all common code.

And to extract css from inline you can use the popular [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin). Webpack docs are not so clear, unfortunately.